# Preserving powerpoint/excel property data after converting to pptx/xlsx

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have vba code to convert a ppt to pptx file, but how do I preserve the file properties (author/created date, modified date, etc)? Here is the vba code that converts the, in this case .ppt file, to a pptx file.

```
Sub BatchSave()
' Opens each PPT in the target folder and saves as PowerPoint 2007/2010 (.pptx) format

Dim sFolder As String
Dim sPresentationName As String
Dim oPresentation As Presentation
Dim bidpList As Collection


' Select the folder:

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fDialog
.Title = "Select folder and click OK"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
If .Show <> -1 Then
MsgBox "Cancelled By User", , "List Folder Contents"
Exit Sub
End If
sFolder = fDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1)
If Right(sFolder, 1) <> "\" Then sFolder = sFolder + "\"
End With

' Make sure the folder name has a trailing backslash
If Right$(sFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
sFolder = sFolder & "\"
End If

' Are there PPT files there?
If Len(Dir$(sFolder & "*.PPT")) = 0 Then
MsgBox "Bad folder name or no PPT files in folder."
Exit Sub
End If

' Open and save the presentations

sPresentationName = Dir$(sFolder & "*.PPT")
While sPresentationName <> ""
Set oPresentation = Presentations.Open(sFolder & sPresentationName, , , 
False)
Call oPresentation.SaveAs(sFolder & sPresentationName & "x")
oPresentation.Close
Wend

MsgBox "DONE"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring object variables for your two presentations will simplify the code a bit, and then you can do something along these lines:

```
Dim oPres As Presentation
Dim oCopyPres As Presentation
Dim x As Long

Set oPres = ActivePresentation
ActivePresentation.SaveCopyAs "c:\temp\test.pptx"
Set oCopyPres = Presentations.Open("c:\temp\test.pptx")

On Error Resume Next

For x = 1 To oPres.BuiltInDocumentProperties.Count
    oCopyPres.BuiltInDocumentProperties(x).Name = oPres.BuiltInDocumentProperties(x).Name
    oCopyPres.BuiltInDocumentProperties(x).Value = oPres.BuiltInDocumentProperties(x).Value
Next
```

You'll want to modify this to set WithWindow false and to use variables as file names, but you're already doing that in the code you have. It should be simple enough to fold in a modified version of the code above.

Comment: I get compiling errors when writing this line: ActivePresentation.SaveCopyAs ("c:\temp\test.pptx") because there is no expression here. Expects a '='

Comment: @Gofurther Remove the parentheses.  Darned if I know why it worked here when I tried it. Sure shouldn't have.  I'll edit the code in my answer as well.  Thanks for pointing this out.